# If a subspace is simply connected, then the space itself is simply connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a "nice" connected topological space. Let $U\subset X$ be a non-empty subspace. Suppose that $U$ is simply connected.

Is $X$ simply connected?

In my application, I'm actually thinking about an open subvariety of a smooth projective connected variety $X$.

Comment: Please do define "nice connected topological space", otherwise there may be lots and lots of counterexamples...

Comment: Note that a one-point subspace is always simply-connected, but really says little about the space as a whole.

Comment: Aren't subvarieties closed by definition? Please be more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

Pick a non simply connected but connected and locally path connected manifold (so that it's "nice" connected), it's locally euclidean so it has an open subset which is simply connected (homeomorphic to an open ball in some $\mathbb{R}^n$).